# Custom Label in Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, customlabel

I have a piece of Javascript in a Visualforce page.  I would like to change the Status of a Case when a button is clicked invoking my Javascript function.  I can't figure out the proper syntax for using a custom label from SFDC.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
     sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!GETSESSIONID()}";
        function Escalate(){
           var confirmMsg = confirm("Are you sure you want to escalate this case to the Client?");
                var c = new sforce.SObject("Case");
                  if(confirmMsg == true){
                     c.id = "{!Case.Id}";
                     c.Escalate_to_Client__c = true;
                     c.Status = "{!$Label.Case_Status7__c}";
                  sforce.connection.update([c]);  
                  }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure that the custom label name ends with  "__c "? Looks more like a custom field name.

Comment: can you try                                                                                                              c.Status = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Case_Status7__c)}';

Comment: @Guy -- That was it.  Wow, was that dumb on my part.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *adding my remark as an answer so the question can be closed by you
>   and won't appear as 'unanswered' in the site statistics

Are you sure that the custom label name ends with "__c "? Looks more like a custom field name. Try this:

```
c.Status = "{!$Label.Case_Status7}";
```